# How to embed HTML help in a form window

Tags: delphi, chm

I'm wondering if it is possible to display topics from a CHM help file in a form of my Delphi application? I know how to use the htmlhelp api but it launches the external help viewer. I would like to display the help topics within a form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested, but...
If you pass the **help url** (like `ms-help://embarcadero.rs2009/delphivclwin32/System__TDateTime__-@TDateTime_@const.html`) to an embedded **WebBrowser**, it should work.

Comment: Thx, it works like a charm. BTW, to find out the URL inside the CHM file right-click on the topic text and select Properties. The file name can be copied from this dialog

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in case you don't want to use MSIE, could be to port the chm reader library from Free Pascal. It is written in the Delphi dialect, and should be fairly easily, and allows you to extract HTMLs from the CHM (and compress back if necesary) without additional external dlls.